# Why doesn't this code work with bootstrap!?? Chosen & Bootstrap Integration failing

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-chosen

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/va4p7b7e/

I am using bootstrap with jquery chosen from (https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/
to modify the select input to allow for a more user friendly interface. But whenever I add a select input type in the second column, it adds padding or margin(?) to the first column (as seen by the blue background in the above JSFiddle).

Anyone know why the green background from the first column doesn't fully cover the first column? It should but it doesn't. If I remove the select and button from the second column, everything seems fine.

I can modify the css of the first column by adding padding to the column but that makes it non-responsive since if I resize the browser, it changes how much padding is needed.

Code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.7.0/chosen.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="background-color: blue;">
            <div class="col-xs-5" style="background-color: green;">
                <select data-placeholder="Choose a genre..." class="chosen-select" style="width:100px;">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-7" style="background-color: purple;">
                <select data-placeholder="Choose a genre..." multiple="true" class="chosen-select" style="width:200px;">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.7.0/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(".chosen-select").chosen(); <!-- Activate Chosen -->
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what actually you want, want to remove the `blue background`..

Comment: Looks and works perfectly for me, could you elaborate on what's going wrong or add a screenshot?

Comment: You should probably consider renaming the title to improve the quality of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using flex, give **display: flex** to parent and **flex: 5; flex: 7;** to child columns

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.7.0/chosen.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="background-color: blue; display: flex;">
            <div class="col-xs-5" style="background-color: green; flex: 5;">
                <select data-placeholder="Choose a genre..." class="chosen-select" style="width:100px;">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-7" style="background-color: purple; flex: 7;">
                <select data-placeholder="Choose a genre..." multiple="true" class="chosen-select" style="width:200px;">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.7.0/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(".chosen-select").chosen(); <!-- Activate Chosen -->
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I had forgotten and didn't realize flex was something I could use. The original purpose of my question was to show that there was something keeping the select input in the first column from centering vertically in the column (as can be seen in your code snippet as well). But your answer led me in the right direction, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div class="row" style="background-color: blue; line-height:35px;">
            <div class="col-xs-5" style="background-color: green;">
                <select data-placeholder="Choose a genre..." class="chosen-select" style="width:100px;">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Add Line height to define a background then its render proper.

Comment: I believe the other answer involving flex was a more elegant solution than hard coded pixel values, since it applies to a larger variety of input spacing issues, but thanks for the response!